# How can I install the Vyos software .iso inside an LXC container?

Tags: lxc, container

I have a problem with the installation of the Vyos software inside an LXC container.  The `.iso` is `vyos-1.1.8-amd64.iso`.

Comment: please refer URL: https://hub.docker.com/r/stano/vyos/ please follow same steps for LXD.

Answer (score 3):

As of last week LXC and LXD v3.0.0 were released.

Although there are many great new features/capabilities, to stay on topic, also released was lxd-p2c which is a tool to allow you to create a local (or remote) LXD container from either a physical machine or a VM.

So you can try now to install the ISO as say a KVM VM.   After installed then create an LXD container using the lxd-p2c tool.

There is a video from FOSDEM 2018 by Stephane Graber demonstrating taking a CentOS VM running Apache and creating a working LXD CentOS container with the Apache running using lxd-p2c:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=8&v=JKztAWZOj9g

The LXD 3.0.0 release announcement is found here:

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/lxd-3-0-0-has-been-released/1491

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  LXC containers are not true VMs, and are designed to operate from prebuilt disk images, not ISOs.

You'd need a VM to properly boot ISOs for installing the OS.  That is achieved by something like VirtualBox, not by LXC/LXD containerization.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the .iso on as a loopback interface and extract the files.  Then use the files to build the container.

There is an [existing Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/2stacks/vyos/), if you want to go that route.

It looks like `lxc-create` will be able to [create the container](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/ol_start_containers.html) from the mounted `.iso`.